Is it correct to train a model with a single feature, and also using observation weights?
I am trying to train a machine learning model where the only input feature is distance. Additionally, I have a weight column that represents the observation weights, and a target variable that indicates whether the distance is high or low (this is the objective I want to predict).
Is it appropriate to train a model with just one feature, in this case, distance? Also, what types of models would you recommend when dealing with weighted data like this?
I tried using models like Logistic Regression and Random Forest with just the distance as the input feature. I expected the model to learn the relationship between the distance and the target variable (high or low). Additionally, I applied the weights to give more importance to certain observations, but I’m not sure if this is the most effective way to approach it or if other models would perform better with weighted data.

can you provide sample data and sample code for what you are trying to do?
try to pass weights as a feature as well and see if that could contribute to the model performance (check feature importance).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
